# Removing items from nested json in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have to manipulate nested json file in way that only one assignment stays.

How it looks now:

```
import json
a = '''
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "Assignments": [
                {
                    "EmployeeId": "1000",
                    "TotalWork": 1,
                    "RemainingWork": 1
                },
                {
                    "EmployeeId": "3L2kVk00x",
                    "TotalWork": 1,
                    "RemainingWork": 1
                },
                {
                    "EmployeeId": "3L2kVk00y",
                    "TotalWork": 1,
                    "RemainingWork": 1
                }
            ],
            "TaskId": "487058",
            "Project": 100
        }
    ]
}
'''

data = json.loads(a)
```

How I want it to look.

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "Assignments": [
                {
                    "EmployeeId": "1000",
                    "TotalWork": 1,
                    "RemainingWork": 1
                }
            ],
            "TaskId": "487058",
            "Project": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

I have written some code like this.

```
data = json.loads(a)
data = data['tasks'][0]['Assignments'].pop(0)
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

but the result is incorrect because it looks like this. There should be tasks and assignments before in it.

```
{
  "EmployeeId": "1000",
  "TotalWork": 1,
  "RemainingWork": 1
}
```

Can you give me some tips?

Comment: Change `data = data['tasks'][0]['Assignments'].pop(0)` to `data['tasks'][0]['Assignments'].pop(0)` (remove `data =`). `pop` returns the removed item. And you're popping the wrong indexes.

Comment: What do you mean?  I can't see the differance

Comment: it didn't help if I will make f.e. print(data['tasks'][0]['Assignments'].pop(0)) I will get same result

Comment: `pop` returns the removed item, so when you say `data = ...` you are assigning the popped item there (Which is why you get that result). You are also popping the wrong items. Even easier would be reassignments as shown in answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach, re-assigning assignments

```py
data["tasks"][0]["Assignments"] = [data["tasks"][0]["Assignments"][0]]
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

When working with large JSON data-set and happen to encounter some syntax errors, you might want to validate your JSON data using [`JSONLint`](https://jsonlint.com/) which is one possible way.

Comment: I run it on huge amount of data and got error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 19 column 4 (char 400 maybe you know how to solve  it?

Comment: This code assumes that the 'tasks' list only has one element which may be fine for the data shown in the question but isn't very flexible

Comment: That clearly tells you that there is a syntax error in your JSON data.  I will suggest you examine your data in line `19`, column 4, char 400 there is a missing `comma`  there and it needs to be fixed. Else wrap your code around `try` and `except`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the input data, it's probably better to create a new structure based on the criteria as stated in the question.

The input data has a list as the value for 'tasks'. Although there is only one element in that list you should allow for an arbitrary size.

```
data = json.loads(a)

result = {}

for d in data.get('tasks', []):
    result.setdefault('tasks', []).append({})
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == 'Assignments':
            for _d in v:
                if _d.get('EmployeeId') == '1000':
                    result['tasks'][-1].setdefault('Assignments', []).append(_d)
        else:
            result['tasks'][-1][k] = v

print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "Assignments": [
        {
          "EmployeeId": "1000",
          "TotalWork": 1,
          "RemainingWork": 1
        }
      ],
      "TaskId": "487058",
      "Project": 100
    }
  ]
}
```